# How to update database by C# ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem like this. I've to update the ContenuReponse to database.
In View of ContenuReponse, I have:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContenuReponse)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContenuReponse)
    </div>
```

(I use express of the template MVC4 Internet App of Edit View for the textbox)
and in Controller of Reponse I have:

```
public ActionResult Reponse(int id = 0)
    {
        Question question = db.Questions.Find(id);
        if (question == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(question);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reponse(Question question)
    {

    }
```

What should I have to do in

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reponse(Question question)
    {

    }
```

to get the value from textbox of View.
Any Ideas ? Thanks a lot for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

In the action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reponse(Question question)
{

}
```

in the Question question argument all the values will be posted to here from the view. You can then use will value and insert it to database. To insert to database I recommend you to use Entity Framework, do a little googling on the same.

Also the best way to understand is to create a breakpoint in this method and see the values posted to the Question question parameter

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have used the <input type="submit" name="reponse"/> for validating.